# Does EJS handle array.map(callback)?

Tags: node.js, dictionary, ejs

I am passing an array of objects to an EJS template, which I would like to map into links using the regular .map() method of arrays. But for reasons I can't figure out, the callback I'm passing to map() doesn't work within EJS the way I'd expect, and I'm getting empty results.

My data is an array of objects, each with a "section" and a "name" key. This array is passed as "entries" to the template:

```
siteHeaders = [ { section: "home", name: "Home"}, 
                { section: "about", name: "About Me"}, 
                ... plus few more ]
```

The template looks like this, and I have it in a local variable called (surprise) `template`:

```
<% entries = entries.map(function(elem) { -%>
  <% return -%>
  <a href="/<%= elem.section %>">
    <%= elem.name %>
  </a>
<% } ) -%>
<p><%- entries.join(" | ") %></p>
```

The result of this template, when I call `require('ejs').render(template, {entries: siteHeaders})` is:

```
          <p> |  |  |  | </p>
```

What I don't get is why this doesn't work in an EJS template, when the corresponding map call works just fine in REPL:

```
> siteHeaders.map(function(e){ return '<a href="/' + e.section +'">' + e.name + '</a>' })
[ '<a href="/home">Home</a>',
  '<a href="/guide">About Me</a>',
  '<a href="/quickstart">Portfolio</a>',
  '<a href="/reference">Blog</a>',
  '<a href="/downloads">Contact</a>' ]
>
```

Any clues?

Comment: I'm just curious why you want to use a map instead of entries.forEach() and output  your html directly.

Comment: No particular reason, except it seems cleaner to me to express the idea of putting pipe symbols between each entry by means of join(). See Vadim Baryshev's answer, below.

Answer (score 7):

This code should work:

```
<% entries = entries.map(function(elem) {
    return '<a href="/' + elem.section + '">' + elem.name + '</a>';
}) -%>
<p><%- entries.join(" | ") %></p>
```

You can't use simple html inside of functions. It's possible only in loops and conditions.

Comment: Bummer. Yes, I thought about your solution, but philosophically that's right back into the old world of manually catenating strings to build HTML, which templating systems are supposed to save us from. That bugged me, so I thought I'd try it in the more node-ish style. Thanks for clueing me in!

Answer (score 3):

It's not as clean as join(' | '), but if you don't want to concatenate, you can do this:

```
<% entries.forEach(function(entry, i, entries){ %>
    <a href="<%= entry.section %>"><%= entry.name %></a>
    <%= i == entries.length-1 ? ' | ' : '' %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't manage to use map in EJS, but I found a way that at least for me is easy too

```
<ul>
  <% for (item of toDoList) { %>
    <li> <%= item %> </li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```