# unexpected token in ejs template

Tags: node.js, ejs

**please can you help me find where the problem is from**

this is the code I have on my ejs file and this is where the problem is from

```
            <% if(user.account.deposits.length){ %>
              <% user.account.deposits.sort(sortFunction).map(history=>{ %>
               <% var className = history.approved ?  "text-success" : "text-warning" %>
               <%  status = history.approved ?  "approved" : "pending" %>
                <% return( %>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row"> <% history.sort %> </th>
                    <td class="<%= className %>"><%= status %></td>
                    <td><%= history.amount %><b> $</b></td>
                    <td> <%= history.date %></td>
                  </tr>
                <% )}) %>
           <%  }else{ %>
              <%  return ( %>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">#</th>
                    <td class="text-light" colspan="3"> You have no deposit history</td>
                  </tr>
               <% ) } %>
```

**with ejs-lint, i am getting**

- Unexpected token (86:32) in views/profile/deposit.ejs
  "><%= status %></td *

**error I am getting in the consolse**

- SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';' in C:######\views\profile\deposit.ejs while compiling ejs *
  i have checked and can't find where the error is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does EJS handle array.map(callback)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260487/does-ejs-handle-array-mapcallback)

Comment: Remove both `<% return( %>` with corresponding ending parentesis.

Comment: @Molda sorry i don't understand what you said I should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when ejs parses your code it turns it into javascript code without the html stuff and this

`<% return( %><tr>`

results in

`... return( ;  __append("\n ...`

and that `;` after `(` causes the error. And since you don't need the `return` at all you can remove it.

The bellow code should work

```
<% if(user.account.deposits.length){ %>
    <% user.account.deposits.sort(sortFunction).map(history=>{ %>
     <% var className = history.approved ?  "text-success" : "text-warning" %>
     <%  status = history.approved ?  "approved" : "pending" %>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"> <% history.sort %> </th>
        <td class="<%= className %>"><%= status %></td>
        <td><%= history.amount %><b> $</b></td>
        <td> <%= history.date %></td>
    </tr>
      <% }) %>
 <%  }else{ %>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">#</th>
        <td class="text-light" colspan="3"> You have no deposit history</td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
```

Comment: i'd like to understand ejs the way you do, can you put me in the direction of some good courses, I've been writing it with the grace of God to my side

Comment: You're welcome. About an hour ago i had no idea how it works. I just had a quick look into the source code and searched for `while compiling ejs` and here it is https://github.com/mde/ejs/blob/main/lib/ejs.js#L681 and if you add a `console.log(src)` just above line 673 you will see the compiled code just before execution. Then it was easy to find the extra `;` Sometimes there's no need for a course when you can simply look into the source code and learn how it works.